# Hot Reloading Causes Exception with Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Hot reloading has been great for instant css reloads. However because we don't use React and have lots of state, it's better to reload the page on any Javascript change.

The issue comes when we enable `Pause on exceptions` during development. When a reload initiates, the hot module system emits an exception which Chrome catches and causes the page to pause: [image of chrome pausing on exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti1Sf.png)

Is there any way to only hot reload css and not Javascript, or to prevent the exception from occurring and causing a pause?

The best solution I've found is the following, but it seems like a hack:

```
if(module.hot) { // check if HMR is enabled
    // accept itself
    module.hot.accept();
    // dispose handler
    module.hot.dispose(function() {
        window.location.reload();
    });
}
```

We are using `webpack@2.2.0` along with `webpack-dev-server@2.2.0`

Comment: While not actually a solution, i found that the exception isn't thrown when developer tools are open, or have been during the chrome session.